# Java 3D Rotation with Distance Constraints

Tags: java, 3d, rotation

I am writing a program with a command that takes 2 coordinate triplets (x, y, z) called a and b (start and end points) and generates a list of points along the line connecting them. Each point is exactly 5 units from the point before it with the exception of the distance between the last point and b possibly being < 5. I have no idea how to do this. Currently I use 2 rotations along the x and y axis and the x and z axis to get a point in the correct direction but slightly more than 5 units from the last point when all 3 coordinates change between the 2 points.

Basically I need to be able to rotate a point on a 3D Cartesian grid then find points on the line connecting the pivot and rotated points.

Answer (score 0):

For given two 3D vectors `p1` and `p2` I'd do something like this:

```
vec3 delta = p2 - p1;
float len = delta.length();
float step = 5.0f;

vec3 dir = delta.normalized();

float t = step;
while( t < len ) {
    vec3 point = p1 + t * dir;    // this is your point
    t += step;
}
```